# Unexpected exception loading stream about exoplayer for mp4

Tags: exoplayer

I used **exoplayer** in our project,but  it occurred a problem about **Top bit no zero** when playing a video for mp4.i will paste exception below,please help me!Thanks a lot in advance.

***The Exception is as below:***

```
Unexpected exception loading stream
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Top bit not zero: -1091358456
com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.ParsableByteArray.readUnsignedIntToInt(ParsableByteArray.java:370)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.readSample(Mp4Extractor.java:433)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.read(Mp4Extractor.java:153)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:635)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```